# Can't get placemark out of reverseGeocodeLocation func Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the function reverseGeocodeLocation to turn coordinates (which I use for pinpoints) to turn into an address.

I've come up with this code:

```
func displayMarkers(/*completion: @escaping (CLPlacemark!)->()*/)
{
    let annotationView = MKAnnotationView()
    var integerCount = 0

    let detailButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = detailButton
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()

    getFromDatabase { (locs) in
        // Hier is "locs" de [CLLocationCoordinate2D] array

    for location in locs{

        let loca = CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)

        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(loca){placemarks, error in
            var placemark : CLPlacemark!
            placemark = placemarks?[0]
            //let streetname = (placemark.addressDictionary?["Street"])
            //let city = (placemark.addressDictionary?["City"])
            //let cityAndStreet = "\(streetname!) \(city!)"
            //completion(placemark)
        }

        //self.displayMarkers { (allPlacemarks) in
            //let streetname = (allPlacemarks.addressDictionary?["Street"])
            //let city = (allPlacemarks.addressDictionary?["City"])
            //let cityAndStreet = "\(streetname!) \(city!)"
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = location
            annotation.title = "Taxi \(integerCount)"
            annotation.subtitle = ""
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
        integerCount = integerCount + 1
        }
    }
```

My question is, I can't get the completion working (so I commented it out).
When I use this completion like this, I get an error in my viewdidload where I call displayMarkers(), the error says I need to put in an argument which I don't have.

Is there any other way how I can get usable information out of it so I can put the address at annotation.subtitle ? I would be really glad to here it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

fix

func displayMarkers(completion: @escaping (CLPlacemark!)->()) {}

to

func displayMarkers(completion: @escaping (_ placemark:CLPlacemark)->()) {}

if it wroks, however, you might better guard the error must to be nil, than you can get the placemarks safely.